# Opening a new window/ document in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

With the following code, I am able to open a new window on a Desktop browser:

```
            var thisWin = window;
            var oauthWin = thisWin.open(data, 'twitter-oauth-window', 'location=0,status=0,width=800,height=400');
            var lastUrl = oauthWin.location.href;
            var meh = true;
            var oauthInt = thisWin.setInterval(
              function()
              {
                if (meh)
                {
                  alert(
                    '\noauthWin.closed: ' + oauthWin.closed +
                    '\noauthWin.location: ' + oauthWin.location +
                    '\nthisWin.closed: ' + thisWin.closed +
                    '\nthisWin.location: ' + thisWin.location +
                    '\noauthWin===thisWin: ' + (oauthWin === thisWin));
                  meh = false;
                }
                // do more stuff here
              }
            );
```

In the debug output within the alert:

```
 oauthWin===thisWin: false
```

Which is what it should be. However, when the same code is run within PhoneGap, I get the following:

```
 oauthWin===thisWin: true
```

Which indicates that PhoneGap has opened the new URL in the same window, replacing the current HTML document.

I wish to open the new URL separately, and to be able to close it upon a certain condition being met, and revert to the old one.

Can this be achieved in PhoneGap, and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now with PhoneGap 2.3+, I was unable to get URLs to open in Mobile Safari in any way. Using _blank didn't work, and I tried window.open(url, '_blank'), but this now opens the URL using the InAppBrowser plugin (which pretty much sucks). I thought it was interesting that that one used a plugin though, so I decided to write a plugin to open URLs using the standard method of opening URLs in iOS apps. You can see/grab the code on [this gist here: https://gist.github.com/typeoneerror/5097118](https://gist.github.com/typeoneerror/5097118).

It's simple enough. In my example, I wired up links that have a class called "_blank" with jQuery and opened those URLs with the plugin call:

```
// execute the plugin called OpenUrl, signature:
// exec(successCallback, errorCallback, pluginName, pluginMethod, params)
cordova.exec(success, error, "OpenUrl", "openUrl", [url]);
```

I'm sure you could rewrite the plugin easily for each platform you require it on. This one is iOS-specific.